# Blender Render (Internal) How to control smoke direction?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I am trying to create a smokey "afterburner" on a spaceship. How do you control the density direction to simulate different environments? In this case, I want to simulate space (zero density?), where "smoke/fire" looking effects should **not** go upward, but should disperse **evenly** in the emitter direction.

[image]

You can see in the picture when the emitter changes direction, the smoke does not change direction as you would expect in space.

I tried:

- Turning down density on both smoke emitter (flow) and box (domain)

  - Smoke still goes straight up
- Using particle system

  - The particles move in the desired direction, but the smoke always floats up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here. You can either control the smoke using initial velocity, particles or using forcefields. Also to stop the smoke from rising turn off the temp difference which should be an option in the smoke domain. To stop it falling, under forces tab turn gravity to 0.

Comment: I was able to achieve non-rising smoke by turning "Temp. Diff." to 0, like you said, but in order to make the smoke "blow", I had to check "Initial Velocity" and turn up "Source" and "Normal". Thanks!

Comment: In Blender 3, it's gravity under Domain > Field Weights to be set to 0 to prevent smoke going up

Answer (score 2):

I would use a wind forcefield with a strength of about 7. Make sure it's pointed in the same direction that you want your smoke to blow in. Keep it a little bit away from the domain, or else smoke would flow around it and it would look weird.

Comment: this solution worked for me. Thanks. ❤️

Answer (score 0):

Select your domain, go to *Physics Settings > Field Weights* and change *Gravity* to -1